# How to stop LED EMI on capacitive touch sensor TTP223

Tags: led, sensor, emc, interference, diy

I am trying to make a piece of wood touch sensitive. I have a piece of wood carved with runic letters.

I inserted LED's inside then filled the letters with epoxy resin.

[image: Wood]

When I touch one I want the LEDs inside to light up. TTP223 has an internal SMD LED.

I desoldered it and soldered wires on the pads. The I connected the wires to the inserted LEDs in the carved wood.

I placed the touch sensors behind the wood as in the picture below. The wires coming from the holes are connected to the LEDs. The problem is, when the LED is unsoldered the touch sensor works great. When I solder the LED to the sensor, the sensor doesnt work. It either works unstable or doesn't work at all. The funny thing is, when I rotate the piece of wood 90 degrees (make it vertical) the not working sensors start working unstable. When I rotate the sensor again, it becomes horizontal, the sensors stop working.

There is just one sensor working normally but I don't know why. I thought that the LEDs might be interfering with the sensors since when I desolder both LED wires the sensors work great. Even if one terminal of the LED is connected, the sensor wont work.
Edit: I saw that the datasheet states that I should not touch the sensor in the first 0.5 seconds of its boot or all the functions will cease. Could this be the problem? The sensor immedieatly gets "touched" and shutsdown?

Datasheet of the [sensor.](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1132200/ETC1/TTP223.html)

[image: sensor]

Comment: That touch sensor uses "capacitive coupling". Idea is that when you touch, it detects capacitance change between two electrodes that is printed on the PCB. The LED in between your finger and the sensor affects the capacitance. Since, the sensing input is high impedance, LED operation induces noise as well. You will need to bring the sensor up on the LED somehow, or make the sensor area larger. Meantime, I like it, and I should build one like that. :)

Comment: Would it work if i decreased the sensitivity? Thanks btw :)

Comment: You should try adjusting the sensitivity. Though, I doubt if that can be a definite solution. The best is avoiding something coming in between the finger and the sensor.

Comment: One thing came in mind. Looking at the bottom right side of the picture, LED leads are almost at the edge of the sensor. Try the higher sensitivity, route LED wiring away from the sensor, make the wood thinner under the touch area. Try twisting the LED wiring. Twisting cancels EMI, if any.

Comment: Sounds like you need better Signal to Noise Ration (SNR).  For touch the best way is to have the distance between the sensor and finger to be very small. Think smart phone, the sensor is behind a very thin glass layer. Can you make your wood/epoxy layer thinner?

Comment: @jay twisting will require insulated wire, the photos indicate non-insulated wire for the LEDs currently.

Comment: Yes, that is when you are desperate, the last small (probably insignificant) part . :) You can cut the LED leads short, use thin wire. If LED operations interfere, that is must try,

Comment: @Aaron no ı cant reduce the distance :( as i said, if none of the LED wires are connected, sensor works perfect.

Comment: @jay ı both increased and reduced the capacitance. Didnt work. I think the LED itself is causing the problem.

Comment: @Tombeki I forgot that part. Try the short lead LED and twisted wire. I think, as you may be already there, how about using an acrylic plate, beaming LED on the side? I don't like it much, but would be a way to push LED away from the sensor.

Comment: @jay That would require me to do the whole carving again :/

Comment: @Tombeki could you post another picture with the sensing side of the touch sensor? Do you have a link to the datasheet, of the circuit PCBA?

Comment: Are you running the LED off of the output pin of this chip? If so, are you sure you are below the 4mA source maximum of the chip? Are you sure the forward voltage of the LED is below 2.4V?

Comment: @Stiddily no i dont run the LED from output pin. The chip has a built in indicator LED. You can sene the pads at the right upper corner of the chip. I simply added extentions to that LED. I drive my leds from that pads.

Comment: @Tombeki it looks like that top pad is connected directly to the IC. I'm assuming that IC is the chip in question and the bare wires to the top right are the LED wires. Might be worth ohming out to rule that out. I'm assuming you have a current limiting resistor attached to the LED?

Comment: @Stiddily you are correct. However, I dont have a current limiter resistor attached. As I said, the chip has a default LED on it. I just replaced the LED. Since the chip had an LED I thought the current limiting was handled internally.

Comment: I doubt that it has a built in current limit. Nothing in the datasheet indicates that. It looks like there is a 121ohm resistor on the board. That may have been the current limiting resistor for the original LED.

Comment: @Stiddily I thought the same. So what can ı do to make the sensor work correctly?

Comment: Try removing that bottom LED extension wire. Looks like it is connected directly to pin 2 (ground). Make sure that the bottom of that 121 ohm resistor is actually connected to pin 2. Then install the LED on those top pads. I can't really get a good look at the full circuit because of all the hot glue.

Comment: @Stiddily ı cant install the LED to the pads, that kills the whole point of illuminating the engravings.

Comment: You can still use an extension wire, just don't short the other end of the extension wire to pin 2 of the IC like in the image you posted.

Comment: @Stiddily wait Im confused. You say instead of connecting the LED directly, I should connect it how?